# Replace ® character with sed

Tags: linux, sed, terminal

I tried
    sed -i 's/®/ /g' filename
but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9K8gCgLRq9zLTQ3c0NaSHdERGs

Any ideas?

Comment: If the file isn't in UTF-8, you need to use tools like iconv to convert it first.

Comment: Using iconv --from ISO-8859-7 --to UTF8 filename.xml > filename2.xml I get the error iconv: illegal input sequence at position 197723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is in `Windows-1253`, Microsoft's ISO noncompliant fork of the standard.

Try this:

```
iconv -fWindows-1253 30005568_2017-3-16.xml | sed 's/®/ /g' | iconv -tWindows-1253 > converted.xml
```